# knockout.js and chunking utility

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

Id like to create some sort of function that will chunk an array into a certain amount and display those in a row.  Below I have an array called pools that would show all pools.  Id like to show three per row though.  The javascript function below works in code, but how would you do this with knockout.js?

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko foreach: pools -->
```

**Javascript**

```
var i,j,temparray,chunk = 10;
for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = array.slice(i,i+chunk);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pools` is an observable containing your data, you can make a `poolRows` computed that calculates based on `pools`:

```
var pools = ko.observableArray([]);

var poolRows = ko.computed(function () {
    var poolRows = [];
    for(var i=0;i<pools().length;i++) {
        var pool = pools()[i];
        if(i % 3 === 0) {
            poolRows.push([]);
        }
        poolRows[Math.floor(i/3)].push(pool);
    }
    return poolRows
});
```

Then:

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: poolRows, as: 'poolRow'} -->
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: poolRow, as: 'pool'} -->
         <!-- pool html here -->
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Ill try this out, looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of objects where each object contains an array of the actual items in your "array" and then a nested loop in ko.

```
 var i, j, tempArray = [], chunk = 10;
 for (i=0,j=array.length, k=0; i<j; i+=chunk, k++) {
    temparray[k] = { items: array.slice(i,i+chunk); }
 }
```

HTML

```
  `<!-- ko foreach: pools -->
      <div class="row">
      <!-- ko foreach: items -->
           <div class="col">`
```